# How to use Java Generics for returing T from String

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to use Java generics for my particular use case. There is a Generic Class `Node` and there will be a lot of implementing class like `NodeBoolean` in this example.

```
public abstract class Node<T>
    {
        T defaultValue;

        public Node(T defaultValue) {
            this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        }

        protected abstract T parse(String input) ;
        public T getValue()
        {
            try
            {
                // here will be some logic to get String value from some db or any other source
                String input = "true";
                return parse(input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return defaultValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Implementing Class

```
class NodeBoolean extends Node<Boolean>
{
    public NodeBoolean(Boolean defaultValue) {
        super(defaultValue);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean parse(String input) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(input);
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
class TestNode
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NodeBoolean node =  new NodeBoolean(true);
        System.out.println(node.getValue());
    }
}
```

Problems I am facing with this approach

1. Suppose there are multiple variants of Constructor of class `Node` then all Implementing class also need to define them for visibility. This problem can be solved using Builder pattern but I am just wondering other possible solutions.
2. There will be a lot of implementing class with having only one override method `parse`. I am looking for a way to define all different parsers based on `instanceof` of `defaultValue` in given example in generic class `Node` itself. And then this `Node` class not be `abstract`.
3. I want to give functionality to define `parse` method which takes `String` and based on the user requirement return `T` value of it while creating object of `Node` class itself. By this way if I have only one occurrence of specific object type of `Node` can be created without defining any new Implementing class.

I am looking for a solution which solves above 3 problems. If I am not clear at any point then let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I think exposing the constructors, or using the builder or factory patterns are the only possibilities here.  But, this can be mitigated by the next answer.
2. Instead of having the `parse` method as abstract, why not pass a function into the node that handles the parsing?

---

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T defaultValue;
    private Function<String, T> parser;

    public Node(T defaultValue,
                Function<String, T> parser) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    public T getValue()
    {
        // depending on the parser, re-parsing every time this is called could get expensive!
        try
        {
            // here will be some logic to get String value from some db or any other source
            String input = "true";
            return parser.apply(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

You can now create a Node by doing this

```
Node<Boolean> node = new Node<>(s -> Boolean.parseBoolean(s))
```

You could also set the default value in the parser function, removing the need to store it in the node - it depends on your requirements.

3. See 2.

**EDIT**
I've using Java 8's Function interface and lambdas here, but you can just as easily do this in Java 1.0 by defining your own Function interface.

```
public interface Function<I, O> {
    O apply(I);
}
```

and then implement this in some way - concrete class, anonymous class, etc - as required for the parsing you need to do.

```
Node<Boolean> node = new Node<>(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(String s) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(s);
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2**

In response to the comment about pre-defined types, you can take a few different approaches.

```
public class NodeFactory {
    private static final Function <String, Boolean> BOOLEAN_PARSER = s -> Boolean.parseBoolean(s);
    .// plus more for integers, double, etc, as required

    private NodeFactory() {
        // no-op
    } 

    public static Node<Boolean> booleanNode(boolean defaultValue){
        return new Node<Boolean>(defaultValue,
                                 BOOLEAN_PARSER);
    }

    // plus more for integer, double, etc, as required
}
```

or you can take the extension route

```
public class BooleanNode extends Node<Boolean> {
    public BooleanNode(boolean defaultValue) {
        super(defaultValue,
              s -> Boolean.parseBoolean(s)); // or use a static parser as in the factory example
    }
}
```

In any case, keeping `Node` non-abstract allows for a lot of flexibility for your users, but your use case may not require that.

Comment: Perhaps you should add that this requires Java 8?

Comment: Using this approach, you could have convenience methods for creating nodes like this: `public static Node<Boolean> boolNode() { return new Node<>(Boolean::parseBoolean); }`. (Also note that you can use method reference syntax here.)

Comment: (except that Java 1.0 doesn't have generics or diamonds, in case someone is maintaining a *really* old codebase)

Comment: @SteveChaloner but I also want to give user some common pre defined parser so they don't have to write it again. like 
`Node<Boolean> node1 = new Node<>(s -> Boolean.parseBoolean(s))
Node<Boolean> node2 = new Node<>(s -> Boolean.parseBoolean(s))
`
Both `node1` and `node2` are using same definition of parser so I don't want to repeat it and using some predefined allow me to force the user for particular parser for particular type.

Comment: If you go down the instanceof route, won't that affect the generic type of the node?

Comment: @SteveChaloner If I chose your Edit2 approach (any of them) then my original problem 1 of having multiple variants of constructor not solved.

Comment: Like I said in the original answer, your choices boil down to n constructors (although you can selectively expose them in subclasses), factories or builders.   Personally, I think too many constructors is often a sign of design  issues (you frequently see this when extension is favoured over composition).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to extend the `Node` class? or just simply create an anonymous class? It is effectively "allow user to define parse method"

```
Node<Boolean> booleanNode = new Node<Boolean>(true) {
    @Override
    protected Boolean parse(String input) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(input);
    }
};
```

And maybe we can have a Factory class that will provide these `Node` classes:

```
class NodeFactory {
    public <T> static createNode(Class<T> classType) {
        if (classType == Boolean.class) {
            return newBooleanNode();
        } else if (classType == Integer.class){
            return newIntegerNode();
        }
    } 

    private Node<Boolean> newBooleanNode() {
        return new Node<Boolean>(true) {
            @Override
            protected Boolean parse(String input) {
                return Boolean.parseBoolean(input);
            }
        }
    }

    private Node<Integer> newIntegerNode() {
        return new Node<Integer>(0) {
            @Override
            protected Boolean parse(String input) {
                return Integer.parseInt(input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in the client, we will have the following

```
Node<Boolean> booleanNode = NodeFactory.createNode(Boolean.class);
Node<Integer> integerNode = NodeFactory.createNode(Integer.class);
```

Comment: Yes I need to extend `Node` class as there are a lot of logics which should be share between all implementing class.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think that question is not well phrased. What I meant to ask is whether you need to create a "full class" (that usually means a dedicated .java file) or anonymous class would suffice. Just for information, creating an anonymous class is similar to extending the abstract class, but is done within another class. In my suggestion, all classes that extend the `Node` class will be declared within `NodeFactory` instead of one .java file for each class.